# How can i populated multiple dropdownlist from data from a single JSON file in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to populate multiple dropdown lists like Gender, State, Religions etc from values in a single JSON file. What is the appropriate way of doing this as I am new to this ? my json file is as follows :

```
[
  {
    "code": "gender",
    "data": [
      {
        "parentId": null,
        "id": "001",
        "name": "male"
      },
      {
        "parentId": null,
        "id": "002",
        "name": "Female"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "code": "state",
    "data": [
      {
        "parentId": "A",
        "id": "01",
        "name": "province1"
      },
      {
        "parentId": "B",
        "id": "002",
        "name": "province2"
      },
      {
        "parentId": "B",
        "id": "003",
        "name": "province3"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

What do we need to do in the controllers and models ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach to this would be to create a model class that replicates the JSON and then read the JSON file in a list of the object models.
For example using this [website](https://json2csharp.com/) you can see what your model may look like:

```
    public class Datum
{
    public string parentId { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}
```